# uploading and attaching files to form wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

What I am trying to achieve is to upload and send some files via form
here's my form:
    `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="contactForm" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contact-form" method="post" class="contactform" >
    <input type="file" name="file" class="attachment" />`
and here's my php:

```
$attachments = array();
        if (isset($attachments))
        {

            $uploadfile = WP_CONTENT_DIR ."/uploads/".$attachments['file']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($attachments['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
            var_dump($attachments);

        }            
        wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments);
```

after dumping
$attachments show empty array and
$uploadfile shows path till uploads/ NO FILENAME HERE
tried to search around the internet but found only answers how to attach a file that is already on the server
any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance
**UPDATE**

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']))
            {
             $attachments = $_FILES['file'];
                $uploadfile = WP_CONTENT_DIR ."/uploads/".$attachments['file']['name'];
                move_uploaded_file($attachments['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
                var_dump($_FILES);

            }
        wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments);
```

**UPD2**

```
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        $this->setError($e->getMessage());
        if ($this->exceptions) {
            throw $e;
        }
        $this->edebug($e->getMessage() . "\n");
        return false;
    }
```

this expeption looks as follows:
exception 'phpmailerException' with message 'Could not access file: ' in /home/ad000min999/public_html/ogo/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php:1971 Stack trace: #0 /home/ad000min999/public_html/ogo/wp-includes/pluggable.php(487): PHPMailer->addAttachment('') #1 /home/ad000min999/public_html/ogo/wp-content/themes/flatads/single.php(244): wp_mail('yucikkravets@gm...', 'asdas', 'Name: asdasd ??...', 'From

Comment: add enctype="multipart/form-data" if you are using file fields. Also, you define $attachments as an array instead of $attachments = $_FILES['file']

Comment: @KaiQing still doesn't send any attachment

Comment: @KaiQing it doesn't even dump anything now

Comment: you'll need to adjust your code accordingly. $attachments['file']['tmp_name'] would now just be $attachments['tmp_name']. and you may want to just var_dump($_FILES)

Comment: @KaiQing still no luck with those changes

Comment: update your question with the revised code below. don't overwrite your old question in case others are helping

Comment: did you also add the enctype to the form: `<form name="contactForm" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="contact-form" method="post" class="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data">` - also, do if(isset($_FILES['file'])){ $attachments = $_FILES['file'] instead. You should always run your isset check before assigning the value

Comment: @KaiQing yes, i did add enctype to the form and i rewrote my code so it does isset check before assignment and still no result

Comment: It's possible WP has something that prevents standard upload methods. Have you looked into the wp_handle_upload function? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload - using the method above should not have issues if the enctype is defined and there is a file in the $_FILES array.

Comment: @KaiQing i forgot one thing, see update

Comment: @KaiQing the 'throw' was commented in testing purposes

Comment: @KaiQing wp_handle_upload seems fine

Comment: Not seeing what "$attachments['tmp_name']" corresponds to - so that might be the issue...